# Determine data-target on Modal launch

Tags: materialize

I am trying to determine what the data-target of the button/anchor that triggered the materialize modal.

HTML

```
<a data-target="testFunction" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#check">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="confirm" class="modal confirmation-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <strong>Modal launch</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="javascript:" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In documentation it indicates that ready option is a callback when the modal launches.

I want to be able to determine the data-target from the anchor in this example using the ready option.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Although the current modal object is not provided in leanModal() function. You can easily find it and do your operations at the right time like this:

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    ready: function() {
        var currentModal=$(".modal:visible"); //This is your currently opened modal
    }
});
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Got id by $(".modal:visible").attr('id');

Comment: @user2217535 yes you can get any property once you have access to the object of modal element.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a pretty way to do this, but here's how to do it an ugly way.

```
    //Remove the .leanModal() calls. Replace with this.
    $('.modal-trigger').click(function(e){

        //get the clicked on link
        var $link = $(e.target);

        //get the data-target of that link
        var data_target =$link.data('target');

        //open the modal
        var $modal = $($link.attr('href'));
        $modal.openModal();
    });
```

Hope this helps.